# Javascript literals for characters higher than U+FFFF

Tags: javascript, unicode, string-literals

My javsacript source code is strictly ascii and I want to represent the [anger symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a2/index.htm) in a string literal. Is that possible in javascript?

Comment: The *Java source code* on that very page happens to also work in Javascript...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript strings are effectively UTF-16, so you can write the surrogate pair using Unicode escapes: `"\uD83D\uDCA2"` (this is what's shown on that page for the Java source code, which also works in JavaScript).

As of ES2015 (ES6), you can also write it as `\u{1F4A2}` rather than working out the surrogate pairs ([spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-literals-string-literals)).

Example:

Using `\uD83D\uDCA2`:

```js
document.body.innerHTML =
  "(Of course, this only works if the font has that character.)" +
  "<br>As \\uD83D\\uDCA2: \uD83D\uDCA2";
```

Using `\u{1F4A2}` *(if your browser supports the new ES2015 feature)*:

```js
document.body.innerHTML =
  "(Of course, this only works if the font has that character.)" +
  "<br>As \\u{1F4A2}: \u{1F4A2}";
```

---

Here's an example using [U+1D44E](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=1D44E) (`\uD835\uDC4E`, `\u{1D44E}`), the stylized *a* used in mathematics, which shows here on SO for me on Linux (whereas your `:anger:` emoji doesn't, but does if I use Windows 8.1):

Using `\uD835\uDC4E`:

```js
document.body.innerHTML =
  "(Of course, this only works if your browser has that symbol.)" +
  "<br>As \\uD835\\uDC4E: \uD835\uDC4E";
```

Using `\u{1D44E}` *(if your browser supports the new ES2015 feature)*:

```js
document.body.innerHTML =
  "(Of course, this only works if your browser has that symbol.)" +
  "<br>As \\u{1D44E}: \u{1D44E}";
```